# Raspberry pi stuck on systemd when running apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, raspberrypi

Hey I just got my raspberry pi 4 and installed the light 32 version but when do sudo apt upgrade it keeps getting stuck at settings up systemd (247 .3-7+rpi1+deb11u2) I have reinstalled and repeated steps from many suggestions but still get the same message or it says dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' but when I run the command it gets stuck then crashes the terminal please please help me

Comment: Try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ this site is for Ubuntu and you are using Raspbian.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your package in your message was **not** built for a Ubuntu system but for Debian 11 as noted in package name thus check your sources if you're on-topic for this site as you've polluted your system with non-Ubuntu packages*